# Tumblr Audio Post Coding Not Working

Tags: tumblr

I am trying to code my tumblr html, and it's going well but i can't seem to get audio posts to show up correctly. Youtube videos are fine, but soundcloud specifically seems to be problematic. I'll try to list the audio coding that i have that i think you need (it's not in the order i block it as)

```
    {block:Audio}
    <div class="postaudio">
    {block:AlbumArt}
    <div class="albumart">
    <div class="album-shine"></div>
    <img src="{AlbumArtURL}" alt="Album Art" />
    </div>
    {/block:AlbumArt}
    {AudioPlayerGrey}
    {block:Caption}
    {Caption}
    {/block:Caption}
    <div class="space"></div>
    </div>
    {/block:Audio}

{block:Audio}
    {block:AudioPlayer}
    <div class="hold">
        <div class="player">{AudioPlayergrey}</div>
    </div>
    {/block:AudioPlayer}
    <div class="audio_info cal">
    {block:TrackName}<span><b>Track:</b> {TrackName}</span>{/block:TrackName}
    {block:Artist}<span><b>Artist:</b> {Artist}</span>{/block:Artist}
    <span><b>Plays:</b> {playcount}</span>
    </div>
    {/block:Audio}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the theme operators to support embedded audio players, such as Soundcloud:

```
{block:AudioEmbed}
{AudioEmbed}
{/block:AudioEmbed}
```

Reference: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#theme-options